# 'BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS' : undeclared identifier

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mfc

I am working on Win32 project in Visual studio 2012. It has file selection button using MFC Editbrowse Control. To write a code for this control, I have added afxeditbrowsectrl.h header file. When I build the solution, it gives me following error:

`1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxeditbrowsectrl.h(67): error C2065: 'BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS' : undeclared identifier`

My question is why this error occurs and how should I remove this error. Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never add only those internal MFC header files. Always include afx.h or afxwin.h. Or if you do this. always make sure that you included afx.h or afxwin.h first.

Otherwise you get Errors like this.

Edit: And never include Windows.h before any MFC include. This will cause additional errors. If you use the MFC just include afx.h or afxwin.h first. Windows.h is included by the MFC include files.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have added afx.h, afxwin.h. Then it gives following error  : `>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxv_w32.h(16): fatal error C1189: #error :  WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not #include <windows.h>` so I added shlobj.h. Then it gives the error which I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: @sayali Do what the error message tells you: stop including `<windows.h>`. Do consider using the Project Wizard to get started; it gets all these little details right automatically.

Comment: @CodyGray : Thank you for the reply. I am making changes in the existing project. I have tried to remove windows.h but it gives me huge list of errors. So removal of windows.h will not work for my project. Is there any other way to solve this error?

Comment: You are supposed to include the MFC header files, not Windows.h. Just include either `<afx.h>` or `<afxwin.h>`. Did I mention checking to see what the Project Wizard does?

Comment: I was still getting compilation error "...BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS is undefined" until I added -- #include <shlobj_core.h>.